# How to get the latest and oldest record in mongoose.js (or just the timespan between them)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, timespan

### Basic problem

I have a bunch of records and I need to get latest (most recent) and the oldest (least recent).

When googling I found [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/mongoose-orm/oldest/mongoose-orm/z93TqQ2lHJ0/PdBpnZ-HPVEJ) where I saw a couple of queries:

```
// option 1
Tweet.findOne({}, [], { $orderby : { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
  console.log( post );
});
// option 2
Tweet.find({}, [], {sort:[['arrival',-1]]}, function(err, post) {
  console.log( post );
});
```

Unfortunatly they both error:

```
TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be a string or object.
```

The link also has this one:

```
Tweet.find().sort('_id','descending').limit(15).find(function(err, post) {
  console.log( post );
});
```

and that one errors:

```
TypeError: Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string or object.
```

So how can I get those records?

### Timespan

Even more ideally I just want the difference in time (seconds?) between the oldest and the newest record, but I have no clue on how to start making a query like that.

This is the schema:

```
var Tweet = new Schema({
    body: String
  , fid: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
  , username: { type: String, index: true }
  , userid: Number
  , created_at: Date
  , source: String
});
```

I'm pretty sure I have the most recent version of mongoDB and mongoose.

### EDIT

This is how I calc the timespan based on the answer provided by JohnnyHK:

```
var calcDays = function( cb ) {
  var getOldest = function( cb ) {
    Tweet.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'created_at' : 1 } }, function(err, post) {
      cb( null, post.created_at.getTime() );
    });
  }
    , getNewest = function( cb ) {
    Tweet.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
      cb( null, post.created_at.getTime() );
    });
  }

  async.parallel({ 
    oldest: getOldest
  , newest: getNewest
  }
    , function( err, results ) {
      var days = ( results.newest - results.oldest ) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
      // days = Math.round( days );
      cb( null, days );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Mongoose 3.x is complaining about the `[]` parameter in your [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) calls as the array format is no longer supported for the parameter that selects the fields to include.

Try this instead to find the newest:

```
Tweet.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'created_at' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
  console.log( post );
});
```

Change the `-1` to a `1` to find the oldest.

But because you're not using any field selection, it's somewhat cleaner to chain a couple calls together:

```
Tweet.findOne().sort({created_at: -1}).exec(function(err, post) { ... });
```

Or even pass a string to [`sort`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort):

```
Tweet.findOne().sort('-created_at').exec(function(err, post) { ... });
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know if it's easy to build a query to calc the timespan between the first and last? Or just query the first, the last and calc the timespan myself inside node?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a single query.  Query both the min and max in parallel and then calc the timespan once both queries complete.  Check out [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) for doing that sort of thing cleanly.

Comment: I tried this query, but both 'created_at' : -1 or 'created_at' : 1 returns the oldest record, how comes? my mongoose api version is 3.8.X

Comment: this method is a old version one, now 3.8 mongoose use `model.findOne().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }).limit(1)` to find the last entry or `model.findOne().sort({ field: -_id }).limit(1)`

Comment: @atom2ueki - will you publish this as an answer rather than as a comment please. This is my personally preferred solution and I will upvote your answer if you do create it.

Comment: Unsupported projection option: sort: { created_at: -1 } when i use this

Comment: @ingrid You may have forgotten one of the two `{}` parameters that must precede that parameter for it to be interpreted as query options.

Comment: sorting on the `_id` is faster than sorting on `created_at` (because of indexing)

Comment: @atom2ueki please post your comment as an answer which is the more suitable answer nowadays!

Comment: @atom2ueki When it is `findOne()` you don't need `limit(1)`

Answer (score 66):

#### Fast and Simple - One Line Solution

Get **`10 latest documents`**

```
MySchema.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(10)
```

Get **`10 oldest documents`**

```
MySchema.find().sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(10)
```

In case you want sorting based on some other property i.e. `createdAt` and get the oldest or latest. It is similar to the above query.

```
MySchema.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(10)  // 10 latest docs
MySchema.find().sort({ createdAt: 1 }).limit(10) // 10 oldest docs
```

Comment: I used `MySchema.find({...}).sort({createdAt: -1})[0]` to get lastest insert and yout query is much faster. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get the last 10 recorded sorted by `createdAt`?

Comment: @philosopher I have updated the answer to answer your question. I haven't tested it, do let me know if it doesn't work or need to improve.

Comment: @WasiF I meant what if I want the documents that are returned in an unchanged order. Anyway I found the solution, what I did was I sorted them after they are returned using Lodash's sortBy.

Answer (score 16):

for version ~3.8 mongoose

to find the last entry

```
model.findOne().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

or using

```
model.findOne().sort({ field: -_id }).limit(1)
```

Comment: Isn't `limit(1)` redundant since you're already using `findOne()` opposed to `find()`?

Comment: what does -id:-1  do?

Answer (score 5):

```
collectionName.findOne().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1).exec(function(err, res){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

This will give you the last document recorded on the database. Just follow the same concept.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

```
await Model.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1); //for the latest record
await Model.find().sort({$natural:1}).limit(1); //for the oldest record
```

This one works for me. using mongodb natural order https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/

Answer (score 1):

We have method called sort using that we can able to **get first element(old document) which means 1 for sort field** or **last element(new document) which means -1 for sort field** of collection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer with async - await

```js
const olderDoc: any = await Model.findOne().sort({ createdAt: 1 }).lean().exec()
console.log('olderDoc', olderDoc)

const newerDoc: any = await Model.findOne().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).lean().exec()
console.log('newerDoc', newerDoc)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have an async function like that:

```
async function findLastElement () {
    return await Mymodel.findOne().sort('-_id');
}
```

this way you get the last element and you ensure reusability.