# How to get latest inserted record from db with same name using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to get latest inserted record which have same name using node.js

Here is my code:

```
gfs.db.collection("file").findOne({ filename:'Sample.txt'}, (err, file) => {
 console.log(file)
})
```

Here I'm finding file name with Sample.txt, In my db I have many docs,and  2 docs with same filename that is Sample.txt, When I  use above function it's return Sample.txt of old inserted data instead of new one So I used sort still it's not working

This is sort code

```
 gfs.db.collection("files").findOne({ filename:'Sample.txt'}, { sort: { 'filename': -1 } }, (err, file) => { console.log(file)})
```

So after using this thing I'm getting details of old Sample.txt instead of new. Can some one please Help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: you can do sort by _id field if you have not added any timestamp field, `{ sort: { '_id': -1 } }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467102/how-to-get-the-latest-and-oldest-record-in-mongoose-js-or-just-the-timespan-bet

Comment: @turivishal I tried this too still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: post example document that you have in collection.